# How to fix Server-side Request Forgery x2 in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, csrf, ssrf

How to maintain a whitelist of externally requested services and hosts and block any interactions that do not appear on the whitelist?

I am looking for some code snippet for implementation of this.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. There are many techniques for avoiding SSRF. White-listing outbound IP addresses is only one of those. There are many techniques for white-listing IP addresses: trying to do it in .NET code is only one of those. Why have you chosen a code-based solution for blocking IP addresses specifically, from among the many ways to avoid SSRF?

Comment: I do not have much knowledge of SSRF. I am doing what i can see in google. Please share  your techniques on this. I do not have server access to try and test things. SO i think code based solution is more suitable to me.

Comment: What you can see in google is probably the best I can offer without knowing a lot more about your situation. Are you taking input from the user and using that to build a URL that your server is making a request to?

Answer (score 0):

you can create an `ActionFilter`, which will check the request host/ip address, compare which db and block request when not found.

```
public class WhiteListedOnlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var ipaddress = getHost(context);

        if(isValid(ipaddress))
        {
           base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
           return;
        }
        else
        {
           context.Result = RedirectToRouteResult(...);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would white-list _inbound_ requests: it does nothing to prevent the server from making requests to other services, which is what SSRF is generally about.

Comment: Then what would be solution. Please elaborate.